# md5(str.encode(var1)).hexdigest() giving hex value as 382fbe213f159eecf85facb256f265d0 - how to know the var1?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pytest, hashlib

While running the test case, my code is failing as the expected value in hex is different then my answer.

for example, my ws_std value is 13.06 i.e. var1

```
md5(str.encode(var1)).hexdigest()  giving hex value as 382fbe213f159eecf85facb256f265d0
```

But I am not sure if it matches with the hex value.

Getting error in below code :-

```
variables = ["ws_std", "p_range", "corr", "dew_month", "max_gust_month", "max_gust_value", "avg_temp", "temp_range", "max_p_range_day", "num_days_std", "median_b_days"]
answers = [ws_std, p_range, corr, dew_month, max_gust_month, max_gust_value, avg_temp, temp_range, max_p_range_day, num_days_std, median_b_days]

answer_dict = dict()

for var, ans in zip(variables, answers):
    answer_dict[var] = md5(str.encode(ans)).hexdigest()

with open('test_files/hash.pk', 'rb') as file:
    hash_dict = pickle.load(file)


def test_ws_std():
    assert hash_dict["ws_std"] == answer_dict["ws_std"]
```

Error Code:-

```
========================================================== FAILURES ==========================================================
________________________________________________________ test_ws_std _________________________________________________________

    def test_ws_std():
>       assert hash_dict["ws_std"] == answer_dict["ws_std"]
E       AssertionError: assert 'c8cc550afa85...2c6946c238f36' == '382fbe213f159...facb256f265d0'
E         - c8cc550afa85496c4ee2c6946c238f36
E         + 382fbe213f159eecf85facb256f265d0

test.py:40: AssertionError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see comments below .
output required :  ws_std

Comment: What about the below error,      ===================================== ERRORS ======================================
____________________________ ERROR collecting test.py _____________________________
test.py:23: in <module>
    max_p_range_day =  re.findall(r'max_p_range_day\s*=\s*\'\d*[-,]?\d*[-,]?\d*\'', out)[0].replace(' ', '').replace("'", "")
E   IndexError: list index out of range
ERROR test.py - IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It is failing for me as well .. Not sure where the error is . Its the same for all . But this one is still an issue.  Please let me know if you are able to resolve .

Comment: got resolved - data["Diffpres"]= data["Maximum pressure "] - data["Minimum pressure "]
filt2 = data["Diffpres"]==data["Diffpres"].max()
date2 =data.loc[filt2]['Date1']
# max_p_range_day = date2.dt.strftime("max_p_range_day = '%s''%Y-%m-%d'")#.values[0]
max_p_range_day = date2.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').values[0]
print("max_p_range_day = '%s'" % max_p_range_day)

Comment: For ws_std , I used the same code . It worked for me .